# How would I use strings inside a for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I apologize for my question not being specific enough but I have no choice. So I received an assignment that hasn't been completely covered in the learning material (even the person assigned to help students is having trouble helping me) since this is beyond basic bash scripting. I'm not expecting anybody to do my assignment but if I can get a clue or an idea it'll be very helpful!

My assignment:

Code a script in bash linux that will use user's input of number of rows and number of columns, and print 'hello' strong according to the user's input, like so:

For example:
User's input of number of columns:2
User's input of number of rows: 3

```
hello hello
hello hello
hello hello
```

I thought in this direction but I can't figure it out and will appreciate any help :)

```
echo -e 'Please enter number of rows: \n'
read rows
echo -e 'Please enter number of columns: \n'
read columns

string='hello'
for i in $columns
do
    echo $string
    string+=$string
done
```

(this is as far as I got with the first loop as what ive done here doesn't work)

Comment: It sounds like two nested loops with an echo inside. Where exactly are you struggling? Getting the user input? Formulating the loops? Writing the output?

Comment: I am struggling with formulating the loops accordingly, especially with the input which im not used to using for loop with inputs

Comment: @lana222 : Your loop is executed only once, with `i` set to the value of $columns. You need the loop to run many times. Have a look at the bash _man_ page, section _Compound Commands_, which explains how a counting loop is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two loops:

```
#!/bin/bash

string='hello'
read -p "x:" x
read -p "y:" y

for ((j=0; j<$y; j++)); do
  for ((i=0; i<$x; i++)); do
    echo -n "$space$string"
    space=" "
  done
  space=""
  echo
done
```

---

See: `man bash`

Comment: God bless your soul.. thank you so much! this is the closest to what I can understand however, can you explain to me the logic behind the ((j=0; j<$y; j++))? it's a bit different from what im used to

Comment: This increments j from 0 in steps of 1 (`j++`) as long as the condition `j<$y` is fulfilled. `((j=0; j<$y; j=j+1))` is also possible. My notation is somewhat inconsistent, because you can omit the `$` within `((...))`.

Comment: @lana222 Note that this works, but looks too much like C and not like a shell script. What you often see is: `for i in $(seq 1 "$rows"); do …; done`. `seq` creates a list of numbers and `for x in words...` executes its loop body once per word

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Please enter number of rows and columns: ' rows columns # prompt and read both vars at once
string='hello' # set string

printf -v row "%${columns}s" # create   var $row consists on N(columns) spaces
row=${row//' '/"$string "}   # recreate var $row changing spaces to "$string "

printf -v col "%${rows}s"    # create var $col consists on N(rows) spaces
all=${col//' '/"$row\n"}     # create full set in var $all by changing spaces to "$row\n"

printf "$all" # print all
```

Testing:

```
$ ./ex
Please enter number of rows and columns: 3 5
hello hello hello hello hello 
hello hello hello hello hello 
hello hello hello hello hello
```

Comment: Slick. Efficient. A little hard to process for less experienced practitioners, but I always like to see variant logic, especially when it eliminates loops. ;)

Comment: Thank you, i've tried to explain every string.

Answer (score 0):

To read inputs you can use [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#CONDITIONAL_EXPRESSIONS) builtin. For example

```
read -r row column
```

- Then you can use `$row` and `$column` variables.
- You'd need a nested `for` loop to print  `row`  x `column` times.
- To not print newlines, use `-n` option of `echo`.

Refer `help read`, `help for`, and `help echo` for details. You can obviously Google these terms, too ;-)

Comment: Instead of nesting the loops, you can also generate a single line in the first loop and store it inside a variable. Then use another loop to print this variable multiple times.

Comment: Of course. You can also do it different ways. For example, use a single loop over row x col times and format the desired output in a single string and print it. I thought a nested for loop is easier to understand and probably the intended exercise to learn for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Do yo want to golf it? :)

```
printf "%$((rows*columns))s" | fold -w "$columns" | sed 's/ /hello /g'
```

To prompt the user for `rows` and `colums`, use the `read` builtin:

```
read -p 'Enter rows: ' rows
read -p 'Enter columns: ' columns
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to get my arguments on the command line.
Accordingly, one implementation (with no error checking...):

```
rows=$1                        # first arg is rows to output
cols=$2                        # second column is columns wanted
str=$3                         # third arg is the string to print

while (( rows-- ))             # post-decrement rows 
do c=$cols                     # reset a column count for each new row
   while (( c-- ))             # post-decrement columns done
   do printf "%s " "$str"      # print the string with a trailing space, NO newline
   done
   printf "\n"                 # print a newline at the end of each row
done
```

Make sure you understand `((`...`))` arithmetic processing, `printf`, and command line argument parsing. All these are available in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html).

For extra credit, do proper error checking of your inputs.

If you need to read the inputs from stdin instead of the command line, replace

```
rows=$1                        # first arg is rows to output
cols=$2                        # second column is columns wanted
str=$3                         # third arg is the string to print
```

with

```
read rows cols str
```

Better, read each with an appropriate prompt - again, details available in the manual.

Good luck.